# Bash ambiguous multiple redirect

Tags: bash, process, posix, io-redirection

For my Operating Systems class we have to implement a shell like program. I've encountered an example I don't know how to interpret:

```
echo "test" > out1 > out2
```

After running this, out1 and out2 are created but out1 is empty and out2 one contains "test".

After I launch the echo process and modify the stdout to be printed to out1, what follows next?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The redirects are being handled from left to right: first `> out1` (which creates `out1` and hooks up file-descriptor #1 to it), then `> out2` (which creates `out2` and hooks up file-descriptor #1 to it, superseding the previous). So it's really just doing the exact same thing twice (`close(1)` plus `fd = open(...)` plus `dup(fd)`), just for two different files.

**Edited to add:** As the *Bash Reference Manual* [puts it](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections):

> Redirections are processed in the order they appear, from left to right.

As POSIX [puts it](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07):

> If more than one redirection operator is specified with a command, the order of evaluation is from beginning to end.

Of course, these explanations only apply if the redirections are really within the same simple command. Something like this:

```
{ echo test > out1 ; } > out2
```

would actually write `test` to `out1` and leave `out2` blank, because the redirection of `{}` occurs before `echo test > out1` gets run.

Comment: It'd be interesting to know if this is a bash only interpretation, or if it is a POSIX defined solution.

Comment: @Rubens: It's defined by POSIX; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07, search for the phrase "If more than one redirection operator is specified with a command, the order of evaluation is from beginning to end."

Comment: @ruakh Very nice answer; you have my +1 up there!

Comment: As an irrelevant but interesting aside, `zsh` has an option (`MULTIOS`) that allows you to combine redirections, so that in this example, both `out1` and `out2` would contain "test". In this, it is similar to the pipeline `echo test | tee out1 out2 > /dev/null`.